# ssh restrict commands using Python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am using a python script to restrict the commands usage using the `command` argument in the `authorized_keys` file.

**command**:

```
ssh host-name bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@"' mkdir -p hello
```

My script is performing required actions to restrict the commands. After filtering, the python script does `sys.exit(1)` for error and `sys.exit(0)` for success. After the return value the above ssh command is not getting executed at the end. Is there something else I need to send from the python script to SSH daemon?

Comment: How does your line in `authorized_keys` look like? How does the  "filtering script" look like?

Comment: command="file-name.py" ssh-rsa=key.

Comment: What is in the `file-name.py`?

Comment: The python script used to allow only some commands to execute.

Answer (score 2):

The `command` modifier in the `authorized_keys` is not (only) used to validate the users command, but that command is run instead of the command provided by the user. This means calling `sys.exit(0)` from there prevents running the user-provided command.

In that script, after you validate the command, you need to run it too!

Comment: so you mean to say I should run `bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@"' mkdir -p hello` using `subprocess.Popen`???

Comment: For example. Or just the content of `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable, after you filter it is "sane" for you.

Comment: yeah it is exactly same. But I feel that running the above command using `Popen` without `shell=True` won't execute. And for security reasons `shell` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think changing it to

```
ssh host-name bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@" && mkdir -p hello'
```

should do the trick, otherwise bash will assume only the part in the single quotes is the command to execute.

If the second part should be executed even if the first part fails, replace the `&&` with `;`

Comment: I think the point is that the shell *only* runs  `mkdir -p hello`, as those three arguments are passed to the `exec` command.